# jQuery load and redirect root directory

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a website for class and am using the load function from jQuery, the load works correctly. I am loading the new page into a table on the existing page to keep the navigation menu the same for all pages.

The problem that I am running into is that the root directory doesn’t change so my external css file and images (located in the child directory) don’t load on the page I just loaded. Is there any way to redirect the root directory to all the supported content so it loads correctly or is this just not possible?  And I need a directory structure for this assignment.

Here is my directory structure. And each website uses the root directory for the css file

/index.html
/css/index.html

```
<a href="javascript:" onclick="load_content('CSS/index.html')">CSS</a>
```

Comment: You need to show your CSS and your web directory structure. Are you aware that images in CSS files are relative to the CSS file, not the document that the CSS was loaded from?

Comment: Are you using that external page for anything else?  Or are you using it just to load as content into your main page?  Why not include all your css on your main page?

Comment: The assignment is to have a main navigation menu on all pages, as a last resort I could add the css to the page itself but since the pages are already created it it would just be more work.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of difficult to understand what you are trying to accomplish.  Perhaps it would be best to disclose the overall goal of what you are trying to do?  What is your assignment?

Without understanding 100%: From a pure web developer standpoint you have a couple of options:

- Move your child's CSS up into the root application's CSS, and all other corresponding assets.
- Include CSS references , or  section at the top, within your loaded page's HTML.  You need to make sure that your child page has the correct path references for your assets.

You can easily remedy a lot of your issues by making good use of CSS classes and ID tags.  This allows you to style your entire application, and ensure that your references stay in tact (being unable to find images).  Also, having all of your style declarations in one section makes it a ton easier to manage.